# Why am I causing the "or die" when trying to open Filehandle?

Tags: perl, stdout, stdin, filepath

Does anyone see the problem here?

```
use FindBin '$Bin';

$scriptdir = $Bin;
$folder= "64521459";
$file = "201608291350_60002015_1_Log-Minim.csv";

print "$scriptdir\\OK\\$folder\\$file";
open (OKBLABLA, ">", "$scriptdir\\OK\\$folder\\$file") or die "Can't create OK folder";
print OKBLABLA "success";
close OKBLABLA;
```

It seems like the `$folder` part is causing problems; when I remove it, it works - any idea why? Won't the script create a fresh directory by itself?

Comment: `open` doesn't create directories... Try `mkdir` instead, or if the parents of  the directory you want to create don't exists, then `make_path` function from [`File::Path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html).

Comment: @Dada thanks, used  "use File::Path qw/make_path/;", works

Comment: Why didn't you ask Perl to include the reason for `open`'s failure in the error message?  `die "Can't create OK folder: $!\n";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `open` cannot create a nonexistent directory, on any platform, in any language I know.

Comment: but it does create files, it was easy to think it would also create folders. uhm, also thanks for correcting my post

Answer (score 1):

The print statement refers to the `$folder` variable.

But the open statement refers to a non-existing `$ordner` variable.

Use `use strict; use warnings;` at the beginning of your script to easily find this kind of issues.

Comment: sorry, thats just a Translation thingy as "ordner" in Germany means "Folder". so thats not the problem

Comment: @ZesaRex Please copy-and-paste the exact code you're using. Otherwise people waste their time hunting down bugs that don't exist in your actual code, and you have to waste time editing your question and responding to answers like this. There's no need to translate variable names to English; we can all read Perl.

Comment: fine, will do so next time :)